# Mysql pdo equal less than greater than characters for date

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using that code without any problem via non-pdo.

```
mysql_query("
  SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE date_start >= '$date_start'
  and date_end <= '$date_end'
");
```

But when I try using with pdo, code didn't work.

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("
  SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE date_start >= :date_start
  and date_end <= :date_end
");

$query->execute(array(
  'date_start'=>'2017-05-01 00:00', 
  'date_end'=>'2017-05-30 00:00'
));
```

Can I get help? Where is problem?

---

MORE INFO : (EDITED)

System : Windows (Appserv)

PHP Version : 5.6.30

I didn't see any error in error.log file.

I guess problem coming from $params array. Because worked like this:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM brands WHERE brand_status=:brand_status and date_start >= :date_start and date_end <= :date_end");
$query->execute(array('brand_status'=>$brand_status, 'date_start'=>$date_s, 'date_end'=>$date_e));
```

But when I used `execute(array($params))` not working. Actually if I not use date parameters working, but when I use date parameters not working. My example code below:

```
$extra = '';
$params = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM brands ORDER BY brand_name";

$brand_status = "1";
$brand_name = "";
$date_start = "2017-05-01 00:00:00";
$date_end = "2017-06-30 23:59:59";

if ($brand_status) {
$extra .= "brand_status=:brand_status and ";
$params[] = array("brand_status" => $brand_status);
}

if ($brand_name) {
$extra .= "brand_name LIKE :brand_name and ";
$params[] = array("brand_name" => "%" . $brand_name . "%");
}

if (dbDate($date_start)==1 and dbDate($date_end)==1)
{
$extra .= "date_start >= :date_start and date_end <= :date_end and ";
//problem here:
$params['date_start'] = $date_start;
$params['date_end'] = $date_end;
}


if (count($params) > 0) {
    if (strlen($extra) > 0) {
        $extra = rtrim($extra, ' and ');
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM brands WHERE $extra ORDER BY brand_name";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result = $query->execute($params);
} else {
    $result = $query = $db->query($sql);
}

if($result)
    $num = $query->rowCount();
if($num > 0) {
    while($row = $query->fetch()) {
        echo $row['brand_name'] . "<br>";
    }
}


function dbDate($value)
{
$pattern = "/^1|2[0-9]{3}\-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])( [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2})?)?$/";
if (preg_match($pattern, $value, $m)) { return 1; } else { return 0; }
}
```

How can I fix that $params problems for dates?  Phil sorry my English is not good. I didn't understand totally your suggestions. I guess you found reason of problem.

```
execute(['date_start' => $date_start, 'date_end' => $date_end])
```

Comment: How exactly does it _"not work"_?

Comment: @Phil - You're correct. I was sure I had that issue before but I guess I was mistaken.

Comment: What did `$date_start` and `$date_end` come out as?

Comment: @user3783243 good question. Seems OP should be using `execute(['date_start' => $date_start, 'date_end' => $date_end])` for a true comparison

Comment: I am getting HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: @webmaster in that case, look in your server's error log

Comment: A status code of 500 is a server error you will need to look at your error logs for the cause. Have you been getting that all along or is that new?

Comment: @user3783243 i am getting this error for only that date parameters. if i remove them and if i put another parameters (without date) working good

Comment: What does your error log show? Please provide example code, are you using the strings provided or the variables? The string Phil provided is for PHP 5.4+ (I believe, maybe 5.6), you may need to maintain your `array(` notation.

Comment: And if you append ':00' ?

Comment: I edited my question with more information and example code. Problem coming from $params array and dates working with normal execute array. Dates only problem in $params array. I am trying understand Phil example `execute(['date_start' => $date_start, 'date_end' => $date_end])`

Comment: `execute($params)` should be correct, `execute(array($params))`will make a second array. I'm not sure I follow the explanation anymore though

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found reason of problem and I fixed my problem. Actually $params haven't any problem in execute array for dates too. Problem coming from `$extra=rtrim($extra, ' and ');` I changed to `$extra=substr($extra, 0, -5);` again and problem fixed.

This is correct sql with substr:

```
date_start >= :date_start and date_end <= :date_end
```

rtrim didn't give any error for other parameters but when I used rtrim for date_end sql it happened this way:

```
date_start >= :date_start and date_end <= :date_e
```

(nd character removed from date_end in sql)

Thanks your answers and your suggestions.